# Testing for Differences within Dependent Samples

Tags: regression, correlation, repeated-measures, model-comparison, independence

I am looking for a way to test for significant differences between two dependent correlations involving different variables and two dependant regression models involving different variables.

Correlation Example - correlation between job satisfaction and engagement when an employee is telecommuting (correlation 1) and working in the office (correlation 2).

Regression Example - performance predicted by engagement when an employee is telecommuting (model 1) and working in the office (model 2).

Comment: I am using a within person design to look at the relationship between performance and engagement in two different contexts and comparing the two relationships (across contexts) to see if the relationship between performance and engagement is different in context 1 vs context 2. Both performance and engagement are measured in each context using the same measures.

Comment: Correlation example - is there a significant difference between Correlation 1 (the correlation between performance measured in context 1 and engagement measured in context 1) vs Correlation 2 (correlation between performance measured in context 2 and engagement measured in context 2).

Comment: Regression example - is there a difference between model 1 (engagement measured in context 1 predicting performance measured in context 1) vs model 2 (engagement measured in context 2 predicting performance measured in context 2)?